# Draw map of building on runtime in Android - Canvas or OpenGL?

Tags: android, performance, canvas, opengl-es

I'm actually implementing a View, which has to draw a floor-plan of a building. I just want to show one floor at the same time but I already got performance issues.

Every floor has x-polygons, which consist out of y-points/edges. I want to draw every point and every edge on my map. In some cases, there are up to 600 points so the drawing takes a lot of time in Canvas.

Is it better to switch to OpenGL? (I don't need any texture, just polygons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go for `OpenGL ES 2.0` if you can't use 2.0 then go for 1.0.

Canvas

- Less Code (and more basic and simple programming)
- Though Worse Performance

OpenGL ES

- More Code
- Usually better performance (The more polygons there are, the easier it will be to see that OpenGL ES gives a better performance)

So if we're talking about a small amount of polygons, then Canvas could be able to handle it while still giving a good FPS.

Though be aware that using OpenGL, will require some more *"thinking"* if you can say it like that. Basically, you need to think about which vertices you want to pack together into `VBOs`, then less draw calls you have the even better FPS you will get. You also need to know some Matrix and Vector math, probably don't 100% need to, but a lot of thing will get a lot more easier if you do know it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! Am I right that with OpenGL it's also possible to view only a "part" of the building? Some kind of viewport-manipulation? So I'm able to zoom in/zoom out or zoom to the left/right to see the building? What do you think how much effort is needed for that? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like having a 3D Camera that you can move around?

Comment: Should be still 2D, it's like I said just a map. I just have two coordinates like Point X (1,2) , Point Y (2,3), Edge (Point X, Point Y). So I just want to zoom in to see "less" of the map or zoom out to see more of it

Comment: Ohh, well yes that is possible! That's just a matter of scaling and/or translating.